# Where is the CMS login page template?

Tags: templates, login, themes

I need to add some logic for a plugin in the CMS login page but I can't find the correct template to modify.

How can I find the template used by /admin.php?

What have I tried so far:

I can see that when it fails to login it goes to `admin.php?/cp/login` this I assume this should be template path name?

[image]

Anyhow, I tried going to `Design > Themes > Member Profile Templates > Default` and select `Login Form` I deleted all content from there but still when I go to `/admin.php` i see the form. I've also done the same with the `Agile Records` but still no luck in making any changes in the template. I've cleared cache after each modification to rule out caching problems.

My other guess that is because we are using an in-house custom theme the system is using that and not the system default one. but when I go to the custom theme folder, there is no login custom page. I can however see that we are using custom CSS but no custom login html form, thus the system cant be using a custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the view file you're looking for is

```
your_web_root/system/expressionengine/views/account/login.php
```

But it's **never** recommended that you edit a core file. See if you can check your custom theme and override it somehow:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/cp_styles/

If that doesn't work, you could possible use an extension hook to modify view output, or craft an accessory to add JavaScript/jQuery to the login page. I'm not sure if accessories are triggered on the login controller.